# Truly protecting data members (of classes/IIFE variables) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Context**

I have been tasked with fixing a big bug on the menu-edit page, which was caused by a stale element issue, caused by the HTML elements for it being rendered server-side. In my three-day fight against this bug, I got some inspiration from Angular and decided to try to make a menu state that will power everything on the page (adding/removing categories/items, and later, pagination of the modals for the adding)

**Some Code**

I came up with this IIFE (to be the "controller" of the MVC. Selector modals hit the add methods of this, and delete buttons hit the remove methods of this. Also, this gets passed to template-render function, which is literally the first thing hit when a modal gets popped):

```
/* all the categories, items, and modifiers that power this page */
var menuState = (function() { 
  let _categories = {
        attached: [],
        available: []
  }, _items = { 
        attached: [],
        available: []
  }, _modifiers = {
        attached: [],
        available: []
  }

  function getExposedMethodsFor(obj) { 
      return {
        all : function() { return obj.attached.concat(obj.available) },
        attached : function() { return obj.attached },
        available : function() { return obj.available }
        // ... other methods that work on obj.attached,obj.available
      }
    }

    let categoryExposedMethods = getExposedMethodsFor(_categories)
    // other exposer objects

    return {
        getAllCategories : categoryExposedMethods.all,
        getAttachedCategories : categoryExposedMethods.attached,
        getAvailableCategories : categoryExposedMethods.available
        // the rest of the exposed methods irrelevant to this question at hand
    }
})()
```

**OK, so what's the problem?**

The problem is that this is false sense of security, it seems. When I try to XSS-test this structure alone, it fails.

I test it with three entities in `_categories`, all of which are `attached`, causing

```
menuState.getAllCategories().length
```

to return 3 and

```
menuState.getAvailableCategories().length
```

to return 0. Good news is that when I tried

```
menuState.getAllCategories().push('a')
menuState.getAllCategories().length
```

I still get three.

**However**, when I go

```
menuState.getAvailableCategories().push('b')
menuState.getAvailableCategories().length
```

I get 1, instead of 0 !!

Is there truly a way to lock down the other getters here?! If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: **NOTE** : before anyone proposes it, using `get`ters on the exposed `getXxx` methods doesn't work. That's part of the reason this took so long, because they didn't work, and I spent so much freaking time and effort trying to *make* it work.

Comment: "*When I try to XSS-test this structure alone, it fails.*" - what does making mutable arrays available have to do with XSS on your website?

Comment: Just use `function() { return obj.….slice(); }` to make a copy of the array before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), which I already used for refactoring the "enums" the dev before me wrote when he was working on this project. What it does is fully protect a state from **any** type of changes, including:

- adding properties
- deleting properties
- modifying properties
- re-assigning the object/array being "frozen"

**How I use it**

In the helper method, I did the following :

```
  attached : function() { return Object.freeze(obj.attached) },
  available : function() { return Object.freeze(obj.available) },
```

This prevents the arrays being changed from those methods, thus shutting down this type of XSS. Also, `menuState` was declared with `const`.

Comment: You should not call `Object.freeze` every time a getter is called. You should freeze your objects once, and then expose them (as a property of by a getter).